# Unmet dependencies error while installing ros-noetic-desktop-full

Tags: dependencies, ros-noetic

I am new to ROS. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to install `ros-noetic-desktop-full`, I am getting unmet dependencies error

```
$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-noetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-noetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I followed the instructions on: (  https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27373/error-while-starting-gazebo-gzserver-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libdart-collision-bulletso6/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem in your source.list
Try this installation guide: https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu